# I2C read from write-protected EEPROM using STM32

Tags: stm32, i2c

I have been trying to read from write-protected area of Microchip 24AA02E48 EEPROM.

I am able to do I2C write and I2C read in the same EEPROM. However, when I want to do a read of the MAC ID I am seeing continuous read, whereas I am not able to do random I2C read.

```
buf1[0] = AA;
buf1[1] = BB;
ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1,(0x50<<1),0x0042, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT,(uint8_t *)&buf1,0x0002,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    
ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1,(0x50<<1),0x0042,I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT,(uint8_t*)&buf2,0x0002,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

The above continuous read works.

The random read from address 0xFA where MAC ID is stored, is not working.

```
ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1,(0x50<<1),0x00FA,I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT,(uint8_t*)&buf2,0x0006,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Not able to get the MAC ID.

Kindly let me know any pointers to this.

Comment: Where does this *not able to get mac id* fail? I assume NAK happens at some point. Where? Do you have an oscilloscope or logical analyser there? Do reads from other addresses work? Does a read need some command before it? You're differentiating continuous read and random read in text, but I'm not seeing a difference in code, how come?

Comment: Hi ravi, Device UID is 6 byte long and you have to read it in a chunk of 3 bytes.

Comment: Define "not able to" - what exactly happens, what was expected, and how are you seeing what is happening?

Comment: not able to get mac id " means when I use ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1,(0x50<<1),0x00FA,I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT,(uint8_t*)&buf2,0x0006,HAL_MAX_DELAY this command my buf2 gives me the same I2C read value which I had used for writing the address location 0x42..means if I write 0xAA and 0xBB in address location 0x42...but the same is seen in I2C_mem_read for address location 0xFA whereas the address from 0x80h to 0xFFh is write protected..thats what I say as MAC ID fails..any change in syntax

Comment: I have a scope and analyser to check for this ...also let me know what is the difference in continuous and random read in the text..kindly let me know will be helpful

Comment: I2C_write and I2C_read are working at locations which are not write protected..but I2C read not happening at write protected area where MAC ID is stored...so wanted to know I am doing random read properly ..since I am seeing the same value as seen in continuous read mode

Comment: kindly let me know how a random read can be done from a write protected area in EEPROM using STM32 HAL API's ??..the address of the location is 0xFA..from where if we do I2C read we should be able to get the MAC ID..thats the required output

Comment: just to update on the environment in which I am using..ac6 compiler..initial code generation using STM32CubeMx...microcontroller part number is STM32L476VG

Comment: to get Random read (HAL_I2C_MEM_READ)using HAL STM32 API's wanted to know how a dummy write can be done so that address is pointing to the required write protected location so as to retrive the data or MACID??